# All the possible reasons that the Linux CPU(s) are Off-line?

Tags: cpu, offline, processor

Stack Overflow, 
We have a server running Red-hat 6 for a period in which we have 2 sockets * 8 cores * 2 threads, since former workmates have left and there is no document regarding this fields: we are now investigating a 'Off-line CPU(s) list' on two specific questions: 
 - Q1. What have caused those CPU(s) offline?
 - Q2. When are those CPU(s) offline caused?

Could there be an enumeration about all the techniques that should cause the CPU(s) to be showing this status?

The "Off-line CPU(s) is showing like below:

[image]

Comment: Have you already ruled out [the obvious case](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-rhel-centos-redhat-suse-hotplug-cpu/)?

Comment: I have the same problem on my old ThinkCentre M715s (AMD PRO A8-9600 R7) with 4 cores, and 2 are disabled. The link from @MargaretBloom did nothing for me and just gave permission errors (yes I used `sudo`).